# select JDBC query not retrieving records in order

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am trying to fetch records from oracle db. I have a select query which has an order by clause implemented. Now when I fire the query on the toad i get the results in correct order. i.e the order of the records at 10:00 AM is like 
Record 1, Record 2,Record 3 and at 10:05 its Record 1, Record 2, Record 3. This is what i need.

Now when iam fetching it through java code, JDBC . I try to iterate the resultset, but here at 10:05 am I am getting the order like Record 2, Record 1, Record 3. Due to this when i am adding the records to the arraylist the order is not mantained.
I dont want to sort the records of arraylist after adding.

Can someone please let me know why using jdbc the records are not fetched in the order we can see using toad ?

Sample code

```
try{
            List<TestObjVO> testResults = new ArrayList<TestObjVO>();
            double statusValue = 0;

            //Connection code

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY);

            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) { 
                testObj = new TestObjVO();

                String date =  rs.getString(1);
                String status = rs.getString(2);
                String svc_nm= rs.getString(3);         


                if("SUCCESS".equalsIgnoreCase(status)){
                    statusValue = 1;
                }else if("ERROR".equalsIgnoreCase(status)){
                    statusValue = -1;
                }

                testObj.setTime(date);
                testObj.setStatus(statusValue);
                testObj.setSvc_nm(svc_nm);

                testResults.add(testObj);
            }
```

SELECT query

```
SELECT to_char(PROBING_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS PROBING_DATE, STATUS, SERVICE_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE PROBING_DATE >= (sysdate-30/1440) ORDER BY PROBING_DATE,SERVICE_NAME
```

Table

```
create table TABLE_NAME(
  probing_date      TIMESTAMP(6) not null,
  status            VARCHAR2(8) not null,
 service_name      VARCHAR2(128) not null
)
```

Comment: add your code please

Comment: Can you add some code to your question please ???

Comment: Show us your actual `SELECT` query including the `ORDER BY` clause and the definition of the tables involved (as `CREATE TABLE` statements)

Comment: Please post your query as well

Comment: please post your complete code to help you

Comment: Are you saying you don't get them in status/service name order within each second? Or that they are not in the order you expect from the fractional seconds, before it should consider the other columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your select to something like this:

```
    SELECT to_char(PROBING_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS PROBING_DATE_STR, 
         PROBING_DATE,
         STATUS, 
         SERVICE_NAME 
    FROM TABLE_NAME 
   WHERE PROBING_DATE >= (sysdate-30/1440) 
ORDER BY PROBING_DATE,SERVICE_NAME;
```

Note there's an extra field returned and is the raw TIMESTAMP field.

Comment: You might want to add, that with your statement the sorting is done on the actual timestamp value. With the original query, the sorting is done on the result of the `to_char()` function which - given the format mask - is not going to work properly.

Comment: yes, that's the real answer, but I was hoping OP tried this and asked why it works, to let him at least trying to get it on his own.

Comment: Thanks BigMike! I think this has resolved the issue.